# How to save repetitive fields to database with a foreign key in PHP / WordPress?

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

The following fields are repetitive / repeated in my form:

```
<input type="text" name="BrotherAdmissionNumber[]" />
<input type="text" name="BrotherName[]" />
<input type="text" name="BrotherGrade[]" />
<input type="text" name="BrotherClassTr[]" />
```

the foreign key comes from this:

$unique_id_generated - this is generated during the form submission and saved in a table called 'admission'

What I am trying to do this is,

I want to insert this into db like one row with one brother details.

so let's say if the foreign key is ZKHYT6 then the rows should be like this for a person who has three brothers.

```
FK      admission No   Name    grade    Tr
------  ------------   -----   -------  ------------
ZKHYT6  7721           John     10      Mrs. Johnathan
ZKHYT6  8975           Bobby    09      Mr. Parkinson
ZKHYT6  6585           Smith    11      Mrs. Camp
```

And I want to insert this to a custom table called '*brothers*' in WordPress.
How to set up this table with a foreign key $*unique_id_generated* from the table '*admission*'

I can do this like below only if these are normal fields

```
$wpdb->insert( 
    'brothers', 
    array(
        'applicationID' => $unique_id_generated, 
        'BrotherAdmissionNumber' => $BrotherAdmissionNumber, 
        'BrotherName' => $BrotherName, 
        'BrotherGrade' => $BrotherGrade,
        'BrotherClassTr' => $BrotherClassTr 
    )
);
```

The above will insert a single row to the table '**brothers**'

How can I insert the repeated fields with a foreign key?

Answer (score 0):

> Better to use in all the fields are required, other wise the data will be saved as blank. Or, You have to use at least one field which one cannot be set as blank. On the basis of that field array we can do the task as you desire. Such as- I'm setting **BrotherAdmissionNumber** field as required.

```
<input type="text" name="BrotherAdmissionNumber[]" required="True"/>
<input type="text" name="BrotherName[]" />
<input type="text" name="BrotherGrade[]" />
<input type="text" name="BrotherClassTr[]" />
```

> After submission of your form -

```
<?php 

  $BrotherAdmissionNumber = $_POST['BrotherAdmissionNumber'];
  $BrotherName = $_POST['BrotherName'];
  $BrotherGrade = $_POST['BrotherGrade'];
  $BrotherClassTr = $_POST['BrotherClassTr'];

  foreach($BrotherAdmissionNumber as $key => $v){
      $data = array(
         'applicationID' => $unique_id_generated, 
         'BrotherAdmissionNumber' => $v[$key], 
         'BrotherName' => $BrotherName[$key], 
         'BrotherGrade' => $BrotherGrade[$key],
         'BrotherClassTr' => $BrotherClassTr[$key]
      );
  }
?>
```

> Now Just Pass the **Array $data** to your query to Insert into **brothers** table. As you were trying -

```
<?php $wpdb->insert( 'brothers',$data); ?>
```

Comment: thank you.. I think this should work.. but before that I forget another step.. could you please check this too : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42222345/how-to-create-a-form-with-hidden-fields-which-were-created-by-repeated-fields-of

Comment: I'll check this one and accept + upvote after I done with the confrimation page too

Comment: How can I show this generated arrays in a page? I mean before inserting to db I just want to show the fields and values.. how can I do that?

Comment: you may use session just before insertion. and then you may take your desired data from there to show in another form. But don't forget to use sesison_unset() to clear the variable data on significant action as you prefer to use.

Comment: this works if I move `$wpdb->insert( 'brothers',$data);` into the `foreach` loop.. update your answer.. I'll accept @Reza Nipun